# Vuex: Sidebar is not Toggling with the value of a state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to toggle Sidebar with a `true/false` value. I have stored this value in `Vuex`.

Like this:

```
state: {
        sidebartoggle: false
    },
    mutations: {
        sidebartoggle(state, item) {
            state.sidebartoggle = item
        }
}
```

Changing this value with a Click Event:

```
<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" @click="changeSidebar"></i>

data() {
        return {
            toggle: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeSidebar() {
            console.log("Cart Clicked!" + this.toggle);
            this.toggle = !this.toggle
            this.$store.commit('sidebartoggle', this.toggle)
        }
 }
```

Try to show the Sidebar like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled" v-if="this.$store.sidebartoggle">
All are working fine. this.$store.sidebartoggle this value is giving true/false also.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked with the Vue Dev Tools if the store is correct? If the mutation has fired?

Comment: Can you create an reproducible example on jsfiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely simplify your approach which may fix up whatever issue you have.

Your state mutation can be simplified by just negating the current state of the sidebar, no need to pass through `item`.

Additinally, you can call this mutation directly by using `mapMutation` and then adding the mutation to the `@click` handler of the `<i>`

And then you can use `mapState` to map the sidebars state (`isSidebarActive`) to a computed property of the same name within the sidebar parent component.

**Vuex**

```
state: {
  isSidebarActive: false,
},

mutations {
  toggleSidebar(state) {
    state.isSidebarActive = !state.isSidebarActive
  }
}
```

**Component with Click Event**

```
<template>
  <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" @click="toggleSidebar"></i>
</template>

<script>
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex'
export default {
  methods {
    ...mapMutations([
      'toggleSidebar'
    ])
  }
}
```

**Sidebar Parent Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="sidebar" v-if="isSidebarActive">
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed {
    ...mapState([
      'isSidebarActive'
    ])
  }
}
```